# Native packaging in java program using netbeans

Tags: java, installation, inno-setup

I get the following error when I try to make .exe installer using Inno setup which is integrated in my Netbeans 8.0. Please help me out.

java.io.IOException: Exec failed with code 2 command [[iscc.exe, /oC:\Users\Aditya\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BillingSystem\dist\bundles, C:\Users\Aditya\AppData\Local\Temp\build7859490274513001371.fxbundler\images\win-app.image\BillingSystem.iss] in C:\Users\Aditya\AppData\Local\Temp\build7859490274513001371.fxbundler\images\win-app.image
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.bundlers.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:131)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.bundlers.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:107)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.bundlers.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:101)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.bundlers.WinExeBundler.buildEXE(WinExeBundler.java:324)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.bundlers.WinExeBundler.bundle(WinExeBundler.java:144)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateNativeBundles(PackagerLib.java:452)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateDeploymentPackages(PackagerLib.java:435)
    at com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask.execute(DeployFXTask.java:215)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:263)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:167)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:247)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1711)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:854)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:164)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:429)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.superDoTopCall(RhinoScriptEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.access$200(RhinoScriptEngine.java:71)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1$1.run(RhinoScriptEngine.java:105)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.doTopCall(RhinoScriptEngine.java:103)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3163)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:175)
    at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context.evaluateReader(Context.java:1159)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:210)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:236)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor213.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.invoke(ReflectUtil.java:108)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectWrapper.invoke(ReflectWrapper.java:81)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.evaluateScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.executeScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:67)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Script.execute(Script.java:52)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor192.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)

Comment: looks like you haven't add the path to the iscc.exe to your system path variable (code 2: file not found). See [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html?print=yes#tool)

Comment: I have added it to the system path variable already using the steps you have provided. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Same problem I am also getting.. Any update on this issue ?